# Data not updating in my sql table

Tags: php, html

I was trying to implement this code but few of the things are not working as stated:

1.I want to update EmailID,Phone and CallStatus fields only but it fetches data from 1st column.
2.When clicked on edit, it shows textboxes and on clicking update button "Record saved successfully" message appears but it is not updated in mysql table.

```
index_data.php
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("contacts");
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM contact";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP Update Data From MySql</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<center>

<div id="header">
<div id="content">
<label>PHP Update Data From MySql</label>
</div>
</div>
<div id="body">
<div id="content">
<table align="center" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>EmailID</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>CallStatus</th>
<th>Edit</th>
</tr>
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($result_set)>0)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result_set))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="edit_data.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row[7]; ?>"><img src="b_edit.png" alt="Edit" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="3">There's No data found !!!</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</table>
</div>
</div>

 <div id="footer">
<div id="content">
<hr /><br/>

</div>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

edit_data.php

```
    <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root");
 mysql_select_db("contacts");
 if(isset($_GET['edit_id']))
  {
  $sql_query="SELECT EmailID,Phone,CallStatus FROM contact WHERE First_name=".$_GET['edit_id'];
  $result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
  $fetched_row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
 }
 if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
 {
// variables for input data
 $EmailID = $_POST['EmailID'];
 $Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
 $CallStatus = $_POST['CallStatus'];
 // variables for input data

 // sql query for update data into database
 $sql_query = "UPDATE contact SET EmailID='$EmailID',Phone='$Phone',CallStatus='$CallStatus' WHERE First_name=".$_GET['edit_id'];
 // sql query for update data into database

 // sql query execution function
 if(mysql_query($sql_query))
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Data Are Updated Successfully');
    window.location.href='index_data.php';
    </script>
    <?php
 }
 else
 {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('error occured while updating data');
    </script>
    <?php
  }
// sql query execution function
 }
if(isset($_POST['btn-cancel']))
{
  header("Location: index_data.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP Update Data From MySql</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<center>

<div id="header">
<div id="content">
<label>PHP PHP Update Data From MySql</label>
</div>
</div>
<div id="body">
<div id="content">
<form method="post">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="EmailID" placeholder="EmailID" value="<?php echo $fetched_row['EmailID']; ?>" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="LastName" value="<?php echo $fetched_row['Phone']; ?>" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="CallStatus" placeholder="CallStatus" value="<?php echo $fetched_row['CallStatus']; ?>" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<button type="submit" name="btn-update"><strong>UPDATE</strong></button>
<button type="submit" name="btn-cancel"><strong>Cancel</strong></button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<div id="content">
<hr /><br/>

</div>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where First_name=$_GEt['id']?is it correct ?

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated better use mysqli or pdo instead of mysql

Comment: I tired using mysqli_query and no records were displayed.It says "No records Found".

Comment: can you please show your table structure?

Comment: WHERE First_name=".$_GET['edit_id'] so youre passing firts name as parameter.?why didn't you pass auto increment id

Comment: SELECT `id`, `ContactOwner`, `LeadSource`, `First_name`, `Last_name`, `AccountName`, `Title`, `EmailID`, `Department`, `Phone`, `Mobile`, `Fax`, `DOB`, `Assistant`, `AsstPhone`, `ReportsTo`, `LinkedIn`, `CallStatus`, `Street`, `OtherStreet`, `City`, `State`, `Zip`, `Country`, `Description` FROM `contact`

Comment: I have millions of records into that and user may not be able to remember id and I have to update record of particular first name

Comment: better you have to pass id because there is chance for multiple field update if duplicates first name exist.your id should be primary key and auto increment it should unique.it's not a good way to pass first name as variable

Comment: `First_name` is an `id`? I think you wanted `where id = `. You need to make a `mysqli` connection to be able to use the `mysqli` functions. You should to that and parameterize this query. This is open to SQL injections.